# move files from directory A to directory B, without duplicating any files

Tags: linux, files, duplicate-files

I am looking to take files from directory B and copy them into directory A. However, I know that are some same named files in each. I would only like to have only the "non-matching" file names copied into directory A.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
mv -n dirB/* dirA/
```

or

```
cp -n dirB/* dirA/
```

From mv and cp man page:

```
-n, --no-clobber
    do not overwrite an existing file
```